# 12 Bit image format with a C++ API?

Tags: c++, tiff

I am working on a biomedical imaging application. I having some trouble finding a good container format for my 12 bit grayscale images.

Does anybody know of a 12 bit image format with a C++ or C api similiar to LibTIFF?

Comment: LibTIFF is a C API which is extremely similar to libTIFF.  Use TIFF and save the images as 16bpp, using only the lower 12 bits.  This is what I have done on two previous projects and it works just fine.

Comment: @EdS., certainly not a bad idea and what I am currently doing. But explaining to somebody that the dynamic range has half the bits chopped off is cumbersome.

Comment: @Mikhail: Why do you need to explain it?  Does that annoyance justify finding a new library?  LibTIFF is a battle-hardened, mature library with a huge existing toolset and a ton of support.  Just embed the bit depth in the image. Anyone reading the image should know how to interpret the data.

Comment: @EdS. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but when I open the image in the commercial editors it scales it from 0-2**16. Oh well.

Comment: @Mikhail: Yeah, that's a good point.  I didn't even think of that because we had written our own reader.

Comment: Are these medical images that require the viewer to adjust the brightness/contrast (level/width)? If so, DICOM is the most logical format to store them.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [DICOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) for medical imaging instead of some other image format. [GDCM](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and [DCMTK](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) are both good opensource toolkits that allow reading and writing of dicom files (+ lots more).

A good free windows DICOM viewer is [MicroDicom](http://www.microdicom.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider researching existing HDR image formats and libraries, like [OpenEXR](http://www.openexr.com/), [HDRi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDRi_%28data_format%29), [Radiance](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/pic/), etc.

Also, as far as I know, TIFF is actually a very flexible format and you could use that.

Comment: Tiff is a wonderful format, but looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068183/writing-10-12-bit-tiff-files-with-libtiff-c I would need to find a different API for using it.